# whats the difference between import a class and do an association in java to use their methods

Tags: java, class, methods, import, associations

Here we have a class code of a chess game. i can see that when we need to use methods of another class, we can do an association, like the class ChessMatch as we can see. but the question is:
why a need to do an association with another class to use their methods while i can just import a class?

```
package chess.pieces;

import boardgame.Board;
import boardgame.Position;
import chess.ChessMatch;
import chess.ChessPiece;         
import chess.Color;

public class Pawn extends ChessPiece {  

    private ChessMatch chessMatch;        
    
        /*CONSTRUTOR*/

    public Pawn(Board board, Color color, ChessMatch chessMatch) {
        super(board, color);               
        this.chessMatch = chessMatch;    
    }

    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: If by "association" you mean passing an instance of `ChessMatch` through the constructor, the answer would be so that you can manipulate and utilize the instance of `ChessMatch` that was already created. Otherwise you would be in an endless loop of each class creating new instances of the other. The `new` keyword creates separate instances (or copies if it helps) of objects, which are all distinct.

Comment: You should read [Meaning of the import statement in a Java file](//stackoverflow.com/q/2903166), because "import" doesn't do what you think it does.